# Extending a module multiple times in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I created a nice extension for Drupal based on the webform module. Now, I need to implement different functionality that is also based on the webform module. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a hook in your module or look for available hooks in Webform, if any. If you didn't create a module, create one. It's the best way to interact with Drupal at any stage of forms/nodes/views etc.

Answer (score 0):

What's a "Drupal extension"? Never heard of such a thing. Now, this question can't be answered, sorry, you need to ask a specific question. The answer might be to write another module which calls back to webform as Kevin suggested but it might be just a crafty hook_form_alter.